# child process shell in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am about to finish my class project which consists of making a shell that executes the commands in /usr/bin/.  If the user mistypes the command, the shell suggests similar commands using hamming techinique. All of this is already done.

When the user enters a command correctly, the shell executes perfectly with no problem. The problem is when the command doesn't exist.  In that case, I create a vector of the candidate commands, which have a Hamming weight <= 1 (that is, they differ from the user's input by no more than 1 character). Then I ask the user which of the commands to execute

For example, if the user types `sipnote` I suggest `zipnote`. If the user inputs 'y' to execute the command, it executes perfectly. The problem occurs afterward, when the execution finishes: it comes back to the top of the routine and for some reason enters the `for` beyond the routine. As you can see at the top of the routine, I put a comment in the `else` where the issue occurs.

The problem is that, for example, if the user types `sipnote` I suggest `zipnote` and he inputs `y` meaning he wants to execute the command suggested.  The command is executed, it returns to the top of the whole routine, BUT it prints then:

"Ingrese su comando" ("Enter your command") and then "Quizo decir [y/n]" ("Did you mean"), which is inside the `for` look, asking the user to choose one of the candidates.

I have no idea why this is happening. What I want to happen is to choose candidate, execute it, then return to the top and start all over again.

Sorry for the long question and bad English, it's not my native language :P

```
int main()
{
    cout << "comienza rutina" < <endl;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "entra a while" << endl;
        // First, load the commands from /usr/bin into memory and save them
        // in a vector.
        string directorio = string("/usr/bin/");
        vector<string> files = vector<string>();
        conseguirComandos(directorio,files);

        char path[80];
        char comando[80];        
        char delims[] = " ";
        char *result = NULL;

        char *argument[10];
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int child_pid,child_status; 

        int dist_hamming = 0;
        vector<string> candidatos = vector<string>();
        char resp[1];

        strcpy (path,"/usr/bin/");

        // "Enter your command."
        cout << "Ingrese su comando" << endl;
        fgets(comando,80,stdin);
        quitar_espacio(comando); 

        if (existe_comando(comando, files) == true)
        {
            result = strtok(comando, delims);

            // Split the user's command on spaces and store each word individually
            // in the argument array.  The system call execv receives the array of
            // char pointers as its second argument.
            while (result != NULL) {
                argument[i] = result;
                i++;
                result = strtok( NULL, delims );
            }

            unir_path_comando(path,argument);
            argument[i] = (char*)0; // Last element must be char *NULL, per execv docs

            char *direccion;
            direccion = path;

            if ((child_pid = fork()) != 0)
            {
                // "Parent is waiting"
                cout << "Padre espera" << endl;
                wait(&child_status);
            } else {    
                // Child process executes the user's command
                cout << "Hijo ejecuta" << endl;
                execv(path, argument);
                //exit(1);
            }
        }
        else // problem is in this section
        {
            int indice = 0;
            int condicion = 0;
            int size_cadena = 0;
            string comando_ejecutar;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
            {
                if (hamming(comando, files[i]) <= 1)
                {
                    // cout << "candidato: " << files[i] << endl;
                    candidatos.push_back(files[i]);
                }
            }

        if (candidatos.size()!=0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidatos.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << "Quizo decir: " << candidatos[i] << " " << "[Y/N]"<<endl;
                scanf("%s", resp);

                if (resp[0] == 'Y' || resp[0] == 'y')
                {
                    indice = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Length of the string containing the suggested command.
            size_cadena = candidatos[indice].length();
            // Store a pointer to the command to execute.
            comando_ejecutar = candidatos[indice];
            // Copy the selected command to a string.
            int m = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < size_cadena; j++)
            {
                m++;
                comando[j] = comando_ejecutar[j];
            }
            comando[m] = 0;

            result = strtok( comando, delims );         

            //se hace un split al comando ingresado por el usuario como delimitador--> " ". Con el fin de tener cada argumento
            //en una casilla distina en el arreglo argument. Ya que el system call execv recibe como segundo parametro un arreglo 
            //de apuntadores a chars conteniendo los parametros del comando.
            int z = 0;
            while( result != NULL ) {
                argument[z] = result;
                z++;
                result = strtok( NULL, delims );
            }
        // Docs say the final argument to execv must be NULL.
        argument[z] = (char*)0;
        strcpy (path,"/usr/bin/");
        unir_path_comando(path,argument);
        char *direccion;
        direccion = path;

        if ((child_pid = fork()) != 0)
        {
            // "Parent is waiting"
            cout<<"Padre espera"<<endl;
            wait(&child_status);
        }
        else
        {   
            // Child executes the user's command.
            cout<<"Hijo ejecuta"<<endl;
            execv (path, argument);
            //exit(1);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            // No candidates to suggest.
            cout << "No tengo nada que mostrar" << endl;
        }
    }   
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it printing "Quizo decir" without waiting for the user to enter the next command?

Comment: the first time u get there it does wait for the input of the user. The problem is this... It prints "Quizo decir" plus the candidate command after using hamming. THe user inputs 'y' implying yes. THe command is executed. and then and here is the problem. It goes to the top of the while and prints "Ingrese su comando" which is what i wants the problem is that after printing "Ingrese su comand" it prints "QUizo decir" again and i have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%s",resp)` reads from stdin until the user enters whitespace.

If the user types `Y<enter>` then `scanf` reads the `Y` but does not read the `<enter>`.

When you return to the top of the loop you call `fgets(comando,80,stdin)` which immediately reads the `<enter>` that `scanf` left behind and returns an empty string.  An empty string isn't a valid command, so you then prompt `Quizo decir [y/n]` again.

If you replace `scanf` with `fgets` it should work OK.

Comment: U were right about the <enter> being read later by the fgets(comando,80,stdin), problem is that if there are multiple candidates and i use fgets it will print "Quizo decir + command" the amount of times there is of candidates and then wait for the input of the user and i want to show 1 by 1. U think that by puttin the char resp[2] instead of [1] will store that <enter> and avoid it from being read by the fgets(comando,80,stdin) on top?

Comment: One of the secret rules of C programming is never to mix `fgets()` and `scanf()`, for exactly this reason.  Unless the program is extremely simple, most programmers always use `fgets()` to read the user's input, and then use `sscanf()` to parse the data.

Comment: fgets solves my issue but the problem with fgets is that it waits to show all commands that are candidates according to their hamming weight and then waits for the user input. The ideal thing to do in this case is to let the chooser choose 1 by 1 can it be achieve this by still using fgets?

Comment: i fixed it i stop putting them in a vector of candidates and just print them as i found them on the hamming loop thx so much for the help!!

Comment: just wanted to say that the "getchar()" function cleared the stdin buffer getting rid of the left the fscan. THx for ur insight ARX didnt know about the left in the buffer!

Comment: @rdk1992: Rather than using `gets` it would actually be better to use `getchar` since you only want a single char (Y/N).  Even better would be a list of numbered commands and let the user pick a number.  (Plus a "show more" option if there are more than ten.)  And feel free to accept my answer my clicking the tick next to it.  Cheers.